# Density Plot on a Parametric Plot 3D

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I am trying to insert a density plot on a parametric plot in 3D, but I am not successful.
I post the part of the code on which I am working on.

```
b2[r_] := r/Exp[r - r0];
z2[r_] := NIntegrate[(t/b2[t] - 1)^(-1/2), {t, 1, r}];
up2 = ParametricPlot3D[{r*Cos[x], r*Sin[x], z2[r]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 
    1, 10}, ColorFunction -> "LakeColors", 
   PlotStyle -> {"LakeColors", Opacity[0.4]}, PlotPoints -> 50];
dp2 = ParametricPlot3D[{r*Cos[x], r*Sin[x], -z2[r]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {r,
     1, 10}, ColorFunction -> "LakeColors", 
   PlotStyle -> {"LakeColors", Opacity[0.4]}, PlotPoints -> 50];
Show[up2, dp2, PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> {False, False, False}, 
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

This is the parametric 3D plot. And I would like to plot on it the following function

```
\[CapitalPhi2][r_] := -a/r;
```

I would like to obtain something similar to this image
[PlotImage](http://www.robertocolistete.net/Python/SymPy/SymPy-Plot_cylindrical-surface-wormhole.png). Could you please help me to fix this issue? Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: You are trying to combine a 2D plot with a 3D one. What exactly would you like as the result?

Comment: Since the figure is axially symmetric, I reduced my density Plot to a 2D function. I would like to plot such function on the ParametricPlot3D. This is a simple case where my density function is a constant, but I guess that once this is issue is fixed, the general case can be easily extended. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, that's still not very clear. Here is something that reproduces the image you included, at least as a concept. See if you can use that as an example of what you woudl like to achieve. `ContourPlot3D[z^2 - x^2 + y^2 == 2, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][#1] &)]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. However it is not what I would like to do. Sorry if I was not clear. I will try to explain clearer my problem: I have a parametric 3D plot and on this plot I would like to add a density plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ColorFunction option of ParametricPlot3D can color the surface according to a function you specify. Here's a simpler example to show the idea without the NIntegrate.

The function you'd like to use as a density plot on the parametric plot has a typo: \[CapitalPhi]2 instead of \[CapitalPhi2]. You don't specify a value for the parameter a, so I set a=1 for this example:

```
\[CapitalPhi]2[r_] := -1/r;
```

The ColorFunction option of ParametricPlot3D has r as its fifth argument. You need to scale the range of the function to the range 0 to 1 for color gradients, e.g., using Rescale:

```
With[{rMin = 1, rMax = 10},
  ParametricPlot3D[{r*Cos[x], r*Sin[x], r}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, rMin, rMax}, 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData["TemperatureMap"][
      Rescale[\[CapitalPhi]2[#5], {\[CapitalPhi]2[rMin], \[CapitalPhi]2[
     rMax]}]] &), 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
]
```

[image: density plot coloring a 3D parametric plot]

Comment: Thank you very much @tad, this indeed a very good and simple solution that I have adapted to my case. Last question, if I would like to insert also the BarLegend, how I should do? Thank you again for your great help!

Comment: You could make the legend manually, e.g., BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", {-1, -1/10}}] and combine with the plot using Legended.

Comment: Thank you very much!